# Mapping an array of Objects having user-id and getting user-details from this user-ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mapping

I have an array of Objects like

```
const array = [{
    text: 'some text',
    userID: '1'
  },
  {
    text: 'another text',
    userID: '2'
  }
]
```

I have to map over this array in React and also get the user details like username & user-dp through the userID. How should I do it. I am using React, MongoDB, NodeJS, Express.

I have tried calling the api to get user-details while mapping the array in my frontend code. It does not render properly as I learned later that we should not call api in the render() method.

Comment: Map to what format? What have you tried?

Comment: Where is the user details? user dp? Can you provide us with the actual array?

Comment: user-details are: username & a url for user photo

Comment: mapping the array to show it in the frontend. The title and user-details.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you mean iterate over it and request the user-details? Then use ```array.forEach(user => { Your request here })```

Comment: Yes I have to iterate it over it and get the user details.

Comment: How to do it? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is not complete, but I will give it a try...
Assuming you have:

```
const array = [{
    text: 'some text',
    userID: '1'
  },
  {
    text: 'another text',
    userID: '2'
  }
];
```

You can do

```
async componentDidMount() {
  // I dont know where the array come from, ill assume it comes from the props...
  const { array } = this.props;
  // Promise.all returning an array of userDetails in the same order than the given array
  const userDetails = await Promise.all(array.map(({userID}) => fetch(`apiUrl/${userID}`);
  this.setState({ userDetails })
};
```

And then you will have access to your details in the render by accessing to your state.

Answer (score 0):

I see this thread is old but i'd like to share my answer anyway.

Since your working with react i'd make a component for every render. Give the component the userId as a prop and use useEffect and useState within the component to fetch the user with the given id and store it in the components state.

So in your rendering view it'll look like:

```
return (
   {
      array.map(item => {
         return <CustomComponent item={item} />
      })
   }
```

And your component will look like:

```
const CustomComponent = ({ item }) => {

const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser(item.userID, setUser);
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        {user && <p>{user.something}</p>}
        <p>{item.text}</>
    </div>
);
```

}